# Call xml element with another activity(android)

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

Sorry for my english. I have `TabActivity` that contains multiple Tab (`FirstTab`, `SecondTab`). It has `TabActivity.xml` which has a picture (as long as it is not visible) .In `SecondTab` have xml adapter. How to do it like this ?: the adapter which belongs SecondTab(`SecondTabAdapter`) a button, if pressed then the picture becomes visible `tabActivity.xml`

[image]

Comment: `TabActivity`  was deprecated long time ago. You should switch to a Solution that makes use of fragments and a horizontal scrolling widget (E.g `ViewPager`)

Comment: @Mattia i have not answer there

Comment: @Blackbelt i almost end my apps. And i dont want all update my program

Answer (score 1):

Create a method for setting image background inside your `TabActivity`. for example

```
setImageBackgroud(boolean status){ 
// logic for setting background
}
```

In your `SecondTabAdapter` add `onClick()` listner to your button.
now inside `onclick()` call above method like

```
getActivity(). setImageBackgroud(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, what do you meet `getActivity()` what is method?

Comment: getActivity() inside Adapter will refers to your TabActivity

Comment: i have error `The method getActivity() is undefined`

Comment: try with getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity()

Comment: `The method getApplicationContext() is undefined`, if i try `context.getApplicationContext().setImageBackground();`then `The method setImageBackground() is undefined for the type Context`